# AVD Manager: Cannot Create Android Virtual Device

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

The OK button is greyed out when I try and create a new AVD device. I have checked for updates and installed the ARM EABI v7a System Image (and the latter system images).

I cannot select a CPU/ABI.

Any ideas?

Comment: were you able to do it before and it has now stopped working? or has it never worked at all?

Comment: no it has never worked before

Comment: Have you chosen a Target API Level and a name for the AVD?

Comment: does it let you choose both `Device:` and `Target:` at the top of the window? And have you chosen a name for the AVD? is there a red X down near the Ok button with any indication of what is wrong?

Comment: I can enter Device, Target and have entered the name. There is no red X indicating a problem.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it happens because any one of the field is not correctly filled, or not available.